# Consider the function $f(z) = \frac{z+6}{z^2-2z-3} $. (Taylor Series and Laurent Series problem)

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

This is a question from a previous qualifying exam that I am working through to study for my own upcoming qual. I'm pretty sure that this one is straightforward and that I did it correctly, but can someone please confirm whether or not it is correct and complete?

**Problem:**

Consider the function $f(z) = \frac{z+6}{z^2-2z-3} $.

(a) Expand $f(z)$ in a Taylor Series about $z=0$ and find its radius of convergence.
(b) Expand $f(z)$ in a Laurent Series in the annulus $1<|z|<3$.

**My Solution:**

We first write $f(z)$ as a sum of partial fractions, such that
$$
f(z) = \frac{z+6}{z^2-2z-3} = \frac{z+6}{(z-3)(z+1)} = \frac{\frac{9}{4}}{z-3} + \frac{-\frac{5}{4}}{z+1}.
$$

Next, we rewrite each term such that it can take advantage of the known geometric series $\frac{1}{1-r} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k$ for $|r|<1$ as follows.

$$
f(z) = \frac{\frac{9}{4}}{z-3} + \frac{-\frac{5}{4}}{z+1} = \frac{-\frac{3}{4}}{1-\frac{z}{3}} + \frac{-\frac{5}{4}}{1-(-z)}.
$$

**(a)** We can now write
$$
\frac{-\frac{3}{4}}{1-\frac{z}{3}} = -\frac{3}{4}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{3^{1-k}}{4} \right) z^k
$$

for $\left\vert\frac{z}{3}\right\vert < 1 \implies |z|<3$ and

$$
\frac{-\frac{5}{4}}{1-(-z)} = -\frac{5}{4} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-z)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)(-1)(-1)^k z^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)(-1)^{k+1} z^k
$$

for $|z|<1$. Thus, by combining these two terms, the function $f(z)$ can be written as the Taylor Series

$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{3^{1-k}}{4} \right) z^k + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)(-1)^{k+1}z^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-3^{1-k}+5(-1)^{k+1}}{4} \right)z^k
$$

with a radius of convergence of $|z|<1$.

**(b)** For the Laurent series, we want a series that will be valid on the annulus $1<|z|<3$. From above, we already have the analytic part of this series, such that

$$
\frac{-\frac{3}{4}}{1-\frac{z}{3}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{3^{1-k}}{4} \right) z^k
$$

for $\left\vert\frac{z}{3}\right\vert < 1 \implies |z|<3$.

We now need to consider $|z|>1 \implies \left\vert \frac{1}{z}\right\vert < 1$. We can obtain the principal part of the series by rewriting

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{-\frac{5}{4}}{z+1} &= \left(-\frac{5}{4}\right) \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)} \\
&= \left(-\frac{5}{4}\right) \left(\frac{1}{z}\right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)(-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)(-1)^{k} z^{-k}
\end{align*} 
$$

for $|z|>1$. We combine the two parts to obtain the desired Laurent series
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{3^{1-k}}{4} \right) z^k + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)(-1)^{k} \frac{1}{z^{k}}
$$

which is valid on the annulus $1<|z|<3$, as desired.

Comment: I can't see any mistakes nor conceptual corrections to make. good job!